# Using ffmpeg to copy file with all streams intact (to fix any issues)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg to copy files with all streams intact to fix various issues with files. ffmpeg is pretty good at reconstructing files and can remove various strangeness various encoders insert. The issue is that it fails on files with covers.

I am currently using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ogg -map 0 -c copy output.ogg
```

But for example on [this file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KR369.ogg) it fails with:

```
Input #0, ogg, from 'KR369.ogg':
  Duration: 01:32:53.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 164 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ALBUM           : Küchenradio.org
      ENCODED-BY      : auphonic.com
      ARTIST          : Philip Banse
      TITLE           : KR369 Hotel Berlin
      PUBLISHER       : Küchenstud.io
      URL             : http://kuechenstud.io/
      DATE            : 2014
      GENRE           : Podcast
      RIGHTS-DATE     : 2014
      RIGHTS          : 2014 CC BY SA
      LICENSE         : http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/
      RIGHTS-URI      : http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/
      ENCODED_BY      : auphonic.com
      comment         : DocPhil, Cindy, Frau Katja und Onkel Andi zu Besuch bei Susanne DeOcampo-Herrmann, der Chefköchin im Hotel Berlin. Wir waren lange nicht mehr zusammen und hatten wie gewohnt alle auf einmal viele Fragen zur: Küchenplanung, Hotelgeschichte, Filetier-Tech
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x500 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
[ogg @ 0x55db241c2e80] Unsupported codec id in stream 1
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

There seems to be a known [issue about it](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4591) but I am trying to see if there is any workaround. Maybe to do something with multiple passes, first manually extracting everything and then reconstructing? Or if there is another tool to use?

Comment: Have you tried to use `-c:a copy` instead of `-c copy` to see what FFmpeg will do with the second stream?

Comment: It makes a video: `Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mjpeg (native) -> theora (libtheora))`

Comment: Not supported. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4448

Comment: Is there some other tool I could use?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Sadly not. The issue is still open.

Answer (score -2):

You need to "unmap" the video stream, I believe using `-map 0 -map -0:v` will un-map the "video stream" (cover) so that you're left with only the audio.

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map for more information.

Comment: This is not what @Mitar wants. He wants to be able to copy every stream from the input to the output.